# Connecting two tables so that results are shown in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume we have table with data like this

```
+----------------+------------+-------+
| Company_number |    Date    | Value |
+----------------+------------+-------+
|            123 | 2017-01-01 |     5 |
|            123 | 2017-02-01 |    10 |
|            123 | 2018-01-01 |    15 |
|            456 | 2018-01-05 |    33 |
+----------------+------------+-------+
```

What should I do to receive data in format

```
+----------------+------+------------+------------+
| Company_number | Mont | Value 2017 | Value 2018 |
+----------------+------+------------+------------+
|            123 |   01 |          5 |         15 |
|            123 |   02 |         10 |            |
|            456 |   01 |         33 |            |
+----------------+------+------------+------------+
```

I have no idea how to select all data from 2017 and connect it using the company number and month with data from 2018.

I have taken all of the records from 2017, put it into another table, and tried to use this select, but it doesn't show records when there are no common months (there is no record for February).

```
select 
s.company_number
,datepart(month,s.date) as Month
,s.Value as Value_2017
,r.Value as Value_2018
from table1 as s
left join table2 as r on concat(r.company_number,datepart(month,r.date))=concat(s.company_number,datepart(month,s.date))
where datepart(year,s.date)='2018'



select results (with no February)
    +----------------+-------+------------+------------+
    | company_number | Month | Value_2017 | Value_2018 |
    +----------------+-------+------------+------------+
    |            123 |     1 |         15 | 5          |
    |            456 |     1 |         33 | NULL       |
    +----------------+-------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please don't use images to show tables values/data, when we try to help you guys one thing that helps a lot, is to create all our test case with just copying the data you post here, we can't do that with images. Take a look at [these tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Which dbms?????  It's one of the most important piece of information to give.  Solutions are based on which dbms you are using.  It's useless to you if people glve you solution to the wrong dbms.  So tag properly!!!

Comment: im using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Fantastic edit!! Side note: `SQL Server 2014 Management Studio` is your database **client**, a program that connects with your database so you can manage it. You are probably using Sql Server 2014 Express (this is a guess based on your client.)

Comment: And what you are looking for is called Pivoting table or Transpose rows to columns. There are tons of answers here with it. Do a quick search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE([t1].[company_number], [t2].[company_number]) AS [Company_Number],
    MONTH(COALESCE([t1].[date], [t2].[date])) AS [Month],
    [t1].[value] AS [2018 Value], 
    [t2].[value] AS [2017 Value]
FROM 
    [table1] AS [t1]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [table2] as [t2] on [t1].[company_number] = [t2].[company_number] 
    AND MONTH([t1].[date]) = MONTH ([t2].[date])
```

Just tried it with (can be copy/pasted in editor and executed) and it works fine:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (Company_number INT, [Date] Date, Value INT)
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (Company_number INT, [Date] Date, Value INT)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (123, '2017-01-01', 5), (123, '2017-02-01', 10)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES (123, '2018-01-01', 15), (456, '2018-01-05', 33)

SELECT 
    COALESCE([t1].Company_number, [t2].Company_number) AS [Company_Number],
    MONTH(COALESCE([t1].[date], [t2].[date])) AS [Month],
 [t1].[value] AS [2018 Value], 
    [t2].[value] AS [2017 Value]
FROM 
    @t1 AS [t1]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    @t2 as [t2] on [t1].[company_number] = [t2].[company_number] 
    AND MONTH([t1].[date]) = MONTH ([t2].[date])
```

Comment: yes, it shows all reords, but it also duplicates records (ieCompany_Number Month 2018 Value 2017 Value
123 1 5 5
123 2 10 10 :(

Comment: Not for me, could you please try the example I attached below the solution?

Comment: it works great!!!!!!, :) i made a mistake on thought it is prolbem of your code :(

Comment: Did you say you can split the data into TWO TABLES? if not, then this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is using CTE on the same table1 NOT TWO TABLES for 2017 and 2018.

```
With tmp as (Select company_id,
```

Datepart(year, dte) as year, 
Datepart(month, dte) as month,
Sum(value) as value
from tbl
Group by company_id,
Datepart(year, dte), 
Datepart(month, dte)) 
Select coalesce(m.company_id,n.company_id) as company_id,
coalesce(m.month,n.month) as month,
m.value as value_2017,
n.value as value_2018
From (select * from tmp 
Where year=2017) m
Full outer join (select * from tmp 
Where year=2018) n
On m.company_id=n.company_id
and m.month=n.month

```
Result:
   company_number   month   Value_2017  Value_2018
    123             1        5                    5
    123             2       10          (null)
    456             1    (null)             23
```